# Refreshing cached Spark Dataframe after a set frequency

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am developing a SparkStreaming solution in which a hive table is cached as a Dataframe and then the stream events will be joined with the cached Dataframe to produce the result.

However the problem is that the Hive table will be updated at certain frequency and hence the cached Dataframe should also be updated accordingly.

Is there any way, say some TTL or any other mechanism around cached Dataframe in which the data gets refreshed automatically at a certain time interval with the updated Hive table records.

Answer (score 0):

Lets get the concept, Cache() function stores the dataframe in the memory, so if any further action you will perform on this dataframe then spark wont trasverse through its DAG from starting of creating the dataframe, its only useful if you perform various action on this dataframe as you are storing the data into memory and initially it will take time to store but further actions will be faster. As per your scenario I wont see any need to cache data as its streaming platform without caching perform the action on the data and store the result in HDFS in append mode.Caching the dataframe will take your cluster memory.

For your question as per my knowledge there is no TTL mechanism to update the cached dataframe. You need to explicitely again read the data and cache it

Answer (score 0):

There is work around for your case. In a separate **Thread**, start one cron job or schedule job with trigger following code after some interval, which you can set based on your requirement.

```
val spark: SparkSession = ???
spark.sql("refresh table <your table name>")
```